# Users dissapear when I sort a doubly-linked list using quicksort

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, quicksort, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly-linked list and I want to sort the users by their ELO.

The problem is that when the function swap() is called, some users dissapear

This is what I get in my console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8chT.jpg

As you can see, the first swap (between players 1 and 2) is done correctly.
But, when it swaps players 3 and 4, user1 dissapears.

I think that the problem is inside the function swap(), but I can't figure out where exactly

Code:
User/Node declaration

```
struct user {
public:
    string username;
    float ELO = NULL; //Score of the user       
    user* next = nullptr;
    user* previous = nullptr;
};
```

QuickSortRecursive function

```
 void ELOManager::_quickSortRecursive(user* low, user* high) {
    if (high != nullptr && low != high && low != nullptr) {
        user* p = partition(low, high);
        _quickSortRecursive(low, p->previous);
        _quickSortRecursive(p->next, high);
    }
}
```

QuickSort function

```
void ELOManager::quickSort(){
    _quickSortRecursive(first, last);
}
```

Partition function

```
    user* ELOManager::partition(user* low, user* high) {
    float pivot = high->ELO;

    user* i = low->previous;

    for (user* j = low; j != high && j!=nullptr; j = j->next) {
        if (j->ELO <= pivot){
            i = (i == NULL) ? low : i->next;

            swap(i, j);
        }
    }
    //i = (i == NULL) ? low : i->next;
    swap(i->next, high);
    cout << endl << "Loop finished -----------------------" << endl;
    printUsers();
    return i;
}
```

Swap function

```
    void ELOManager::swap(user* A, user* B) {
    user* tmp = new user();
    user* swapperVector[4];

    cout << endl << "swap1[" << A->username << "]" << endl;
    cout << "swap2[" << B->username << "]" << endl;

    if (A == B) {
        cout << "Same Users: Continue" << endl;
        return;
    }   

    swapperVector[0] = A->previous;
    swapperVector[1] = B->previous;
    swapperVector[2] = A->next;
    swapperVector[3] = B->next; 

    if (areTheyNeighbours(A, B)) {
        A->previous->next = B;
        A->next->previous = B;
        B->previous->next = A;
        B->next->previous = A;


        A->previous = B;
        B->previous = swapperVector[1];
        A->next = swapperVector[3];
        B->next = A;    
        cout << endl << "Option 1" << endl;
    }
    else {
        A->previous = swapperVector[1];
        B->previous = swapperVector[0];
        A->next = swapperVector[3];
        B->next = swapperVector[2];

        A->previous->next = B;
        A->next->previous = B;
        B->previous->next = A;
        B->next->previous = A;
        cout << endl << "Option 2" << endl;
    }

    cout <<"Print list after swap" << endl << "-----" << endl;
    printUsers();
}
```

Feel free to get into my project's github
https://github.com/pablogalve/ELO-System

I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Have you tried using `std::list`, which is a doubly-linked list that solves your problem?

Comment: That's a complicated-looking doubly-linked list swap. Have you tried writing some simple tests for the swap, and single-stepping through if they fail, before layering quicksort on top of it? Learning to debug this stuff yourself is kind of essential.

Comment: I took a look at lists, but I see that each cointainer has space only for 1 element and I have more. I have username(string) and ELO(float)

Comment: @eduinvestor You can define a type that contains both and put those in your list.

Comment: @eduinvestor you already have a `user` type. You can just drop `next` and `prev` and use `std::list<user>`

Comment: Aside: You `new` a temporary `user`, never use it, and don't `delete` it.

Comment: A merge sort for linked lists is probably faster, especially in worst case situations, and merge sort for linked lists is an in-place merge sort. You could consider using std::list and std::list::sort(), which is usually a merge sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if (areTheyNeighbors(A, B))` block, your linked list pointers end up looking like this: [image: pointers]
Notice that:

- Both of B's pointers are pointed at A
- Both A and `A->next` think B is their previous list element

This causes multiple problems in list traversal, and might be what causes the first element in the list to be lost.

If A and B are neighbors, this should swap them properly.

```
A->previous = B;
B->previous = swapperVector[0];
A->next = swapperVector[3];
B->next = A;
```

Answer (score 1):

Amanda's answer shows one way to deal with adjacent nodes, but there doesn't need to be a special case to handle adjacent versus non-adjacent nodes, if the swapping is done first by swapping what is pointing to the two target nodes, then swapping the pointers within the two target nodes.

```
    AP = A->previous;
    BP = B->previous;
    AN = A->next;
    BN = B->next;
    std::swap(AN->previous, BN->previous);
    std::swap(AP->next, BP->next);
    std::swap(A->previous, B->previous);
    std::swap(A->next, B->next);
```